# VS 2022 Hot Reload - web socket fails to open in aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

Reagrdless of whether I run the application with or without the debugger attached, and whether it's run from VS or via command line (`dotnet watch run`) I cannot get the Hot Reload websocket to connect.

The framework automatically adds the aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js file to my page, which attempts to open a websocket connection to a localhost port on machine, but it always fails.

I tried creating new blazor server project to see if the issue still happened...it did.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and targeting .net 6. Both are up to date.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue and/or have any ideas to try to resolve?

Comment: This issue seems to be related to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/741393/error-with-websocket.html

Comment: Have you resolved this issue??
I'm using VS code with .net7 sdk and I'm getting this error when i use "dotnet watch run" from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug with VS2022 that should be addressed in the near future;

I bet you have 17.1.0 or 17.1.1;

As a workaround, you can uninstall Visual Studio 2022 17.1.0 version and install and older version; VS2019 also works but you might not get .net 6 with that.

Comment: I can confirm that I have issue with 17.1.0 and 17.1.1; however, I *thought* I had this happen prior to upgrading to 17.1, but I could be wrong there. I have not seen much reporting with other people with same issue. Do you have any details about the issue or any info on the ticket to allow us to track when this gets patched in a future VS update?

Comment: See [this](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/WebSocket-connection-to-wss:-fail/1670519?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest) link - it looks like a fix is awaiting release

Comment: Can confirm the error has gone with VS 17.2.0 preview 2.1 (like stated in the [link](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/WebSocket-connection-to-wss:-fail/1670519?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest) above). Hope this fix will be released soon.

Comment: Just installed 17.1.4 release and can confirm it is still an issue.

Comment: Still an issue for me in 17.3.5

Comment: Just downloaded 17.4.4 and the issue seems to be resolved in that release. So far so good.

Comment: for 17.4.4 I experience the exact same bug.

Comment: Still an issue for me in 17.5.1

Comment: Still an issue for me in 17.5.2

Comment: Confirmed that still happening in v17.5.2 Visual Studio for Mac, however hot-reload works fine, but it is not neat to see this error in chrome developer console

Comment: Still an issue for me in 17.6.4

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error too when updating to 17.1.1. But I can overtake it by changing the version to preview via Visual Studio Installer. For this case i have update to 17.2.0 preview 2 and the error gone :) .

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you've overriden the base href of your application? If so, this is a known issue logged here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39554 and seems there is currently no fix to it. Good thing is it is planned for .NET 7

Comment: No, I have not overridden the base href

Comment: I still have this issue in Community 17.5.0 Preview 5.0.